# .XLSX files which are generated using jasper report 6.17.0 are opening with error

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-excel, dynamic-jasper

I'm working on jasper reports and the .xlxs file that gets generated from the jasper gives this error
**We found a problem with some content in 'DetailedQuoteReport ISX003178-001.xlsx. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.**
However the PDF, word, .xls file are getting generated and opened fine.
I'm unable to rectify the cause. The code in order to generate the excel is below

```
    public ByteArrayOutputStream export(JasperPrint jp) {
    Exporter exporter =exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    
            // Here we assign the parameters jp and baos to the exporter
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jp);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, baos);
            if (ReportOutputType.XLS.equals(reportOutputType) || ReportOutputType.XLSX.equals(reportOutputType)) {
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.FALSE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.FALSE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_CELL_BORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
                 
            }
    
            try {
                exporter.exportReport();
    
            } catch (JRException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
    
            return baos;
        }
```

The jasper Version that I'm using is 6.17.0 ,
Dynamic jasper = 5.3.3 ,
poi =  5.2.0 ,
poi-ooxml ,ooxml-schemas - 1.4 .
As soon as I click on yes in the excel popup the excel opens successfully but why the error prompt is coming? Please help

Comment: An issue which relates to this was [reported](https://community.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports-library/issues/14316) and resolved as far as I know in 6.20.0. Try to upgrage the latest Jasper version.

Comment: @zforgo thanks but I've tried this and it didn't work . :(

Comment: As @Axel Richter
notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75975141/xlsx-files-are-opening-with-error-popup-using-apache-poi-and-jasperreports#comment134000187_75975141), see the [_Component Map_](https://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components).